# How to get current time of different countries in C#

Tags: wpf, windows, c#-4.0, timezone

**How to get current time of different countries in C#** by using following any parameters,
1.country name
2.Timezone of country

This is for **Windows / WPF Applications**, not like Web
Could anyone please answer this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These things are for sale.  For example: http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at `TimeZoneInfo` class, specifically at [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx).

For example, to get current time in Central Europe:

```
var remoteTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var remoteTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, remoteTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} is {1}", remoteTimeZone.Id, remoteTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
```

Comment: This does not provide the current timezone of a country, it just allows you to get information of a known timezone.

Comment: The question is about getting time zone information, based on country name or similar identifier, not about getting the local time zone of the process or host.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Country");
        var Input= Console.ReadLine();
        string InputConcatenate = (Input + " Standard Time");

        TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(InputConcatenate);
        DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
        Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}", tst.IsDaylightSavingTime(tstTime) ?
                          tst.DaylightName : tst.StandardName, tstTime);
        Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tstTime, tst));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```