# how to get current datetime using id of country in c#?

Tags: c#

How to get current time of different countries in C# by using following any parameters:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time of different countries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066303/how-to-get-current-time-of-different-countries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime.Today for a specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135997/datetime-today-for-a-specific-time-zone)

Comment: Which paramters ?

Comment: country name and current time